# need to update value of a property in all objects of an array of objects

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

In my angularjs application have an array of objects as shown below :

```
$scope.rowData = [{
    "expNum": "678",    
    "itemHr": "10", 
    "highRe": "C"
    }, {
    "expNum": "978",    
    "itemHr": "3",  
    "highRe": "Y"
}]
```

Now on a click event I need to update 'itemHr' of each object in the array to some new value let say (25). I don't want to create new Array of object rather modify the existing only. If we can use angularjs utilities to do it or underscore library,  both are fine for me.  can any one help me with that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not vanila js with for loop?

```
for(var i = 0; i<$scope.rowData.length; i++)
{
   $scope.rowData[i].itemHr = 25;
}
```

or underscore

```
_.each($scope.rowData, function(item){ item.itemHr = 25;});
```

or angular

```
angular.forEach($scope.rowData,function(item){ item.itemHr = 25; });
```

```js
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
 
    app.controller("maincontroller", function($scope) {
       $scope.rowData = [{
            "expNum": "678",    
            "itemHr": "10", 
            "highRe": "C"
           }, {
            "expNum": "978",    
            "itemHr": "3",  
            "highRe": "Y"
           }];
       $scope.update = function(){
          for(var i = 0; i<$scope.rowData.length; i++)
          {
             $scope.rowData[i].itemHr = 25;
          }
         
       }

    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="maincontroller">

<head>

   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <script data-require="angular-bootstrap@0.12.0" data-semver="0.12.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div>
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" >
               <tbody >
                  <tr ng-repeat="row in rowData">
                     <td>
                        {{row.expNum}}
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        {{row.itemHr}}
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        {{row.highRe}}
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
   </div>
  
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="update()" value="Update ItemHr to 25">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Artiom, I have accepted the answer  but small note, when I give item.itemHr = 25, it is not working instead if I give item[itemHr] = 25, it is working fine

Comment: @MadasuK don't know why it didn't work for you. Check the sample

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.forEach($scope.rowData, function(item,index){
   item["itemHr"] = "25";
})
```